# Discord Bot js reactions

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Coding a discord bot trying to get it to react to a user adding a reaction and then remove that user's reaction, I managed to get that working but if there is more than one message with the reactions on it, it will run that reaction as well. For reference I'm trying to make a dice rolling bot that reacts to a users reaction and then re-rolls a previously entered roll. I do apologise if there is already a question like this but I could not find it when looking.

Here is an example:
[example of bot in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbggZ.png)

This is the code
Get command

```
Client.on('message', message=> {
if(!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX) || message.author.bot) return;
let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

switch (args[0].toLowerCase())
{
  case "roll": case "r":
          if(!args[1] || args[1].indexOf("d") == -1) return message.channel.send('Invalid Roll');
          Client.commands.get('torg').RollDice(message, args, Client);
          break;
}});
```

This is then the code it gets.

Run command

```
module.exports = {
name: 'torg',
description: 'Die roller for Trog',
async RollDice(message, args, client)
{
    const channel = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    const reRoll = '';

    if(!args[2])//untrained
    {
        var roll = DieRoller(args[1]);
    }
    else if (args[2] == "t" || args[2] == "T")
    {
        var roll = DieRoller(args[1], true);
    }
    
    let rollEmbed = await message.channel.send(roll);
    rollEmbed.react(reRoll);

    client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => 
    {
        if(reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
        if(reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
        if(user.bot) return;
        if(!reaction.message.guild) return;

        if(reaction.message.channel.id == channel)
        {
            if(reaction.emoji.name === reRoll)
            {
                var newRoll  = DieRoller(args[1]);
                await message.channel.send(newRoll);
                await reaction.users.remove(user);
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

What should I do to make sure that the bot doesn't react twice when it sees two messages with reactions?

Thanks in advance to anyone who reads this and can help, I've only recently tried my hand and coding discord bots.

Comment: You should really fix your brackets and/or download a formatter.

Comment: @a2br Although that has nothing to do with answering the question could I ask you to explain further about what's wrong about the brackets? This is just how I was taught to code.

Comment: Your answer made me look into formatting standards, and I discovered that there's nothing wrong with your brackets. I thought putting brackets on the same line was a JS standard, but it looks like I'm wrong, it's just that I've never seen code like that. I'm sorry!

Comment: @a2br no worries, I'm sure there's multiple formatting standards, truth be told I haven't looked into it much. I just write in a way that makes it easy for me to read. Apologies for my previous message, in hindsight it was a bit aggressive.